# Когда "не" пишется слитно?

Tags: орфография, частица-не

Известно, что "не" с глаголами пишется раздельно. Но в каких случаях "не" нужно писать слитно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Не" пишется слитно довольно часто.

- Если слово не употребляется без "не".
  Примеры: *неудачник, недотепа*.
- Если частица "не" меняет смысл слова на противоположный.
  Примеры: *нерусский, неволя, невероятный*.
- С прилагательными, если к ним можно подобрать синоним без "не".
  Примеры: *некачественный (бракованный), небыстрый (медленный), недалекий (близкий или глупый, если речь о человеке)*.
- С причастиями без пояснительных слов.
  Примеры: *ненадкушенное яблоко (не надкушенное ребенком яблоко), некомпетентный врач (не компетентный в своей специальности врач)*.
- С местоимениями, если "не" не отделено предлогом.
  Примеры: *никому, некто, некий (не к кому, не в чем, ни у кого).*
- С наречиями: незачем, нехотя, несмотря на, невзирая на, неужели.
- А также - в приставке "недо-"
  Примеры: *недоработатка, недосып**а**ть, недоношенный.*

Answer (score 3):

*Не* с глаголами пишется слитно, если слово не употребляется без *не:* нездоровится, негодовать, недоумевать, неистовствовать, ненавидеть.

Это относится к деепричастию и почти ко всем частям речи.

Answer (score 0):

Некомпетентный в своей специальности врач.

Компетентный - это прилагательное, а наличие зависимых (пояснительных слов), как правило, не означает, что *не* с прилагательными пишется раздельно.

Например: незнакомый нам автор, неизвестные науке факты, неуместное в данных условиях замечание.

Раздельное написание не с прилагательным встречается при наличии в качестве пояснительных слов отрицательных местоимений и наречий (начинающихся с ни) или сочетаний далеко не, вовсе не, отнюдь не, например: никому не известный адрес.